# Asymptotics: Why is $\log^2(n) \in O(n)$?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I know that $(\log_{2}(n))^2 \in O(n)$, but right now I don't really see how to prove it, even though I assume it's fairly easy.
Could anyone help me out please?

Comment: In fact $\log^2n\in o(n)$.

Comment: Start by writing down the definition of $O(n)$. Then let us know where exactly you are stuck with the proof.

Comment: Do you know the argument for why $\log(n) \in O(n)$?

Comment: A hint: $\int^\infty_0x^22^{-x}dx=\frac{2}{\ln^32}$ is finite.

Comment: Yes, I know why $log(n)$ is in $O(n)$, although thinking about I I think we never actually did any proof for that in my lecture and just took it as a given fact... 
Well we're (as in in our class) are usually supposed to prove f(n) in O(g(n)) either by induction or by proving directly that there is a constant factor $c$ such that for all  $n>n_{0} \in N : f(n) \leq c \cdot g(n) $. So in this case $(logn)^2 \leq c\cdot n \implies n^{logn} \leq 2^{cn}$ and I honestly don't see where I would be going with this...

Comment: @j.lnhrt: if you don't see how to prove it, how do you know $(\log_2(n))^2\in O(n)$? I assume that you learn it from some references and you are looking for a proof, right? If that is true, giving that reference and saying explicitly that you are looking for a proof could help preventing your post from being closed or even deleted. There have been 3 close votes to your question so far. Lifting your comment to the post could also help.

Answer (score 1):

L'Hôpital's rule can be used to see that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac {\ln^2n}n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac {\frac{2\ln n}n}1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac {2\ln n}n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac {\frac2n}1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac 2n=0.$$

So in fact $\ln^2n=o(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the big-O notation with the limit superior we can say that
$$
\lim\sup_{x\rightarrow \infty} |\dfrac{\log_2^2 n}{n}| < \infty \implies \log_2^2 n \in O(n)
$$

The limit on the left is equal to 0, as $n$ grows significantly faster than $\log_2^2n$

Comment: Thank you. I'm actually not too used to working with limits but I guess I really need to read up on that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually,
$\log(n) \in O(n^c)$
for any $c > 0$.
This implies that
$\log(n) < K(c)n^c$
for some $K(c)$
for all large enough $n$,
so
$(\log(n))^{1/c}
\lt (K(c))^{1/c}n
$
so
$(\log(n))^{1/c}
\in O(n)
$.

Then set $c = 1/2$.

To show
$\log(n) \in O(n^c)$:

$\begin{array}\\
\log(n)
&=\int_1^n \dfrac{dt}{t}\\
&=\int_1^n t^{-1}dt\\
&\lt\int_1^n t^{-1+c}dt
\qquad\text{since } t^{-1} < t^{-1+c}\\
&=\dfrac{t^{c}}{c}|_1^n\\
&=\dfrac{n^{c}-1}{c}\\
&<\dfrac{n^{c}}{c}\\
&\in O(n^c)\\
\end{array}
$